# space between top of browser or frame and document body

Tags: html, css

I have a page with a image. I want set it top of page.

```
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
   <title></title>
   <style>
    html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
   </style>
 </HEAD>
 <BODY style="background-color:#3baa35;" >
  <a href="" ><p align="center"><IMG border=0 src="home.PNG"  ></p></a>
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

But there is one line of space between the top of the page and the body.

How to set image top of page?

Comment: Can you post some more of your stylesheet? My hunch is that the `<p>` tag has some styling on it that creates that space.

Edit: Looks like someone got to it first :)

Comment: A lot of browsers have default margins/padding on both the `<body>` tag and `<p>` tags, which would push your image down from the very top of the page.

Comment: @Tom : No, I don't have any style.

Comment: This code looks like quirks. If this is the case, the browsers will render weird stuff and ignore standards.

Comment: @ar.gorgin Then you are subject to default stylings on anything other than the margins and padding of your `html` or `body` tags (since you have written style rules for those). As several answers indicate, it is probably default styling on your `p` tag. Also, as Michas just pointed out, you need a doctype (`<!DOCTYPE html>`) at the top of your page to prevent some browsers (like IE) from dropping into Quirks mode (which you *do not want*). Also, don't use the `style` attribute on tags. Put your `background-color` into the `style` tag, or better yet put all your styles in a linked CSS file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put some styles:

```
p { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Comment: Yes. This will do the trick. The explanation would be under the default box model, the <p> tag is assigned a default attribute of margin: 1em which is infact one line of text or around 16px. So even you remove the padding: 0 part from the answer it will work...

Comment: @AnaMaria well noted.

Comment: Some extra unneeded info. The 1em always does not equal 16px. 1em indicates the size of the letter M of the parent element...

Answer (score 1):

This is because each browser has its own default CSS values. You can use Eric Meyer's reset CSS to have the same display on all the browsers :)

[Link to Reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to put `border: none;` as well

Answer (score 0):

IMO, your css properties are okay .
as

- Margin is on the outside of block elements
- We use padding for inside of block elements  .

**By default, images align their bottom edges with the baseline of the text**.

just use to get rid from this

```
 img {  /* Or a suitable class, etc. */
    vertical-align: bottom;
  }
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hack to your answer.
Your *p* tag inherits the font-size from the *a* tag and thus assigns the margin to a size of 1em which is the size of the letter M of the parent elemt i.e **THE a tag**
So if you set the font-size of a to 0 then the font-size of p will be 0 and hence the margin too.
Sounds pretty cool right? Here's a working fiddle...
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/X6pnq/)

```
a{
font-size:0pt;
}
```

WARNING: This is just for Demo purposes and should not be used in actual working code.